# How do I tell pbr to use pytest when setup.py test command is invoked?

Tags: python, pytest, python-pbr

While using `pbr` to simplify Python packaging what do we need to configure in order to make it use `pytest` when `python setup.py test` command is executed.

Running `pytest` works without any problems.

Answer (score 3):

In setup.py:

```
setup(
    setup_requires=['pbr>=1.9', 'setuptools>=17.1', 'pytest-runner'],
    pbr=True,
)
```

In setup.cfg (after standard pbr config):

```
[aliases]
test=pytest
```

In test-requirements.txt (same directory as requirements.txt):

```
pytest
```

If your tests are outside the application code, you will also need to specify your test directory using addopts in setup.cfg. For example, if your directory structure looks like the first example on [this page](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html), you should have

```
[tool:pytest]
addopts = tests
```